# Extracting user profile data from Alexa Channel- address, email, phone number, name

Tags: botframework, alexa-skills-kit

I have looked into the **stepContext.Context.Activity.ChannelData**, but I do not see these fields are available. Is this the correct place to look for these fields?

Also, would it possible to use any of these libraries to extract the fields, although I am not using the adapter based approach, but through Bot Channel=Alexa.

https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Alexa.Core

because when I tried

```
var profileClient = new CustomerProfileClient((SkillRequest)stepContext.Context.Activity.ChannelData);
                    FullAddress x = await profileClient.FullAddress();
```

it errors out with

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Alexa.NET.Request.SkillRequest'.
```

Instead, should I be writing my own set of methods with this as reference?

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html

Because I have been getting the below response using the endpoint and token

```
{
    "code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
    "message": "Access denied with reason: ACCESS_NOT_REQUESTED"
}
```

If so, how should the permission card be sent, is there a sample message activity that can be leveraged?

Appreciate if someone can direct me on the right path here please.

Comment: @KyleDelaney would you know a way out here please

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with this. I code in python so I will be adding code snippets in that only. I assume it will not be difficult to understand.

1. You will have to enable Permission in your Alexa skill Kit and specify the fields which are required by the skill. You will find this under the tools section.
2. For permission card, you will have to send the response in the following JSON format.

```
{
        'outputSpeech': {
            'type': 'SSML',
            'ssml': "<speak>" + output + "</speak>"
        },
        'card': {
            "type": "AskForPermissionsConsent",
            "permissions": [
                
                "alexa::profile:given_name:read",
                "alexa::profile:email:read"
                                ],
            'title':  title,
            'content':  cardContent
        },
        'reprompt': {
            'outputSpeech': {
                'type': 'SSML',
                'ssml': '<speak>' + reprompt_text + '</speak>'
            }
        },
        'shouldEndSession': should_end_session
    }
```

3. Check wether account is linked or not.

```
def checkAccountLinking(session):
    try:
        consentToken = session["user"]["permissions"]["consentToken"]
        accountLinked = 1
    except:
        accountLinked = 0
    return accountLinked
```

4. Following is the code snippet to get the data provided by the user.

```
def getlinkdata(session,event):
    consentToken = session["user"]["permissions"]["consentToken"]
    apiaccesstoken = event["context"]["System"]["apiAccessToken"]
    apiEndpoint = event["context"]["System"]["apiEndpoint"]

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + consentToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    try:
        
        responsename = requests.get(apiEndpoint +'/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.givenName', headers=headers, verify=False)
        name = json.loads(responsename.text)
    except:
        name = " "
    
    try:
        responseemail = requests.get(apiEndpoint + '/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email', headers=headers, verify=False)
        email = json.loads(responseemail.text)
    except:
        email = " "
    userdata = [name, email]

    return userdata
```

You can add other permission also. Follow this [document](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html). I hope this helps you. Feel free ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you @ashish, yes thats the same document I am referring to. Can you outline, as to what endpoint you are sending that JSON payload to? Botframework as such, doesnt directly allow use to send a JSON Payload as is.